# Slider or carousel with html form in top

Tags: html, css

I have this image [image] and I don't know how to put in html and css with a slider. Is there a slider or carousel like this? I'm not a pro and that is why I wait some ideas please.
I was thinking to make a normal slider and the form to be separated and put in in the top of the slider with absolute, but I don't know if is the best idea.

Comment: show your code that you have tried

Comment: You could take a look at the frameworks Bootstrap or Foundation, they have some nice carousels and other features. Bootstrap - http://getbootstrap.com/components/  Foundation - http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/

Comment: I'm sorry but I  didn't start any code yet because I wanted some ideas first, from you guys, to see how to do it.

Comment: you can refer this link http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#demo,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** create a slider using Slider Plugins example : BXslider.com(http://bxslider.com/) where you have the demo to create the sliders.

**Second** u need to create the tabs widget using HTML and CSS and use the plugin idTabs(http://www.sunsean.com/idTabs/) which can be helpfull.